# CS Student: Learning to program on Linux vs my Mac

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, operating-system, opensuse

My teacher wants us to familiarize ourselves with the Linux terminal, and do our programming on Linux for at least our first lab. Since I enjoy working on my own computer, I am wondering if my Mac OS Capitan terminal is sufficient to learn Linux commands since they both use Bash.

**My Main Question**
Is it beneficial for me to set up dual booting Linux on my computer, or is practicing terminal use on my Mac's OS enough? Whats so special about Linux that will benefit me in the CS world?

Thank you very much for the information..

Comment: There is a whole world of applications that use shell scripts. A computer professional should be skilled at using the shell interface. If you have to user Linux and you want to use your own computer, you will have to dual boot. If you can learn on the terminal window and do your labs on a different, Unix system, you don't need to dual boot.

Comment: That depends on what your teacher actually wants you to learn. If sticking with tools defined by POSIX (and not using any implementation-specific extensions) suffices, it doesn't matter if you use Mac OS X or Linux.

Answer (score 1):

As someone interested in CS, if you have the time to set up a dual boot, go for it. Mac and Windows both try to insulate the user from the inner workings of the machine as much as possible, assuming that the user probably doesn't want to (or is unable to) deal with debugging strange OS related problems. In Linux though, things will break (a lot), and it will be up to you to figure out what the problem is and how to work around it. You will learn a lot about computers in general by just setting up the dual boot, and using Linux as your main operating system for a while. Personally, I know my applicable CS knowledge skyrocketed once I started exploring Linux and its quirks.

If you are less interested in becoming a better "computer person" however, and just want to learn how to use terminal, I imagine using the standard Mac terminal with `homebrew` should be similar enough to meet your needs.

Comment: This is a very good answer to my question. To elaborate, CS is my major, and I am every bit motivated to be as knowledgable as possible. As someone who used windows and transferred to a Mac it was hard for me to really understand why my professor is pushing Linux on us since it just seemed like an interface change to me. I certainly would like more detail on the skills/possibilities Linux use opens up, but you've already given me enough reason to get started on my dual boot. My school uses Linus OpenSuSE, is there any reason not to use that one as well?

Comment: I haven't used OpenSuSE before, so I can't say whether or not it will be a good choice as a first Linux OS. At first glance, it seems to be geared towards system admins and small businesses, but I can't point out any particular reason it would be a bad choice. The most popular choice for getting into Linux is Ubuntu - it is one of the most user friendly, and its dual boot installation process will probably be the least painful. I can also recommend Fedora as pretty good OS to start out with.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go to the VM way. VirtualBox plays nice on OS X. Running Linux inside a full screen will give you almost the same user experience compared with a dual boot installation and the advantage of don't need to reboot.

Answer (score 1):

OS X should be sufficient to learn all that you need. Most of the GNU tools (and others) that make up the Linux user space, also run on OS X. It is a pretty complete *nix experience. It should be. OS X is descended from BSD. Use a package manager like `brew` to install pretty much everything on OS X.

Else go the VM route. Install `Virtual Box` [[link]](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), and install Linux in a VM. You will have OS X and Linux running simultaneously. Get to experience both. Much better than the dual boot option. You don't need to keep booting into the OS that you want to work with. You can run Linux in a VM full screen on one desktop. You won't be able to tell that it's not a dedicated Linux machine.

The guest machines run at pretty much native speeds. So you don't really lose anything. And you get the additional capabilities of taking machine snapshots, the ability to move the whole machine to a different host, etc.

Comment: Thanks very much. I think the VM route is the way for me.